# Regex also matching numbers

Tags: regex, numbers

I want that the value only matches letters and special characters. But not numbers. So my regex looks like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z äÄöÖüÜß,-\;\.]{3,})$
```

The problem is, that the regex accepts also numbers.
So what is wrong?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-` defines a range. In your case: range between `,` and `\`. You have to escape it too:

```
^([a-zA-Z äÄöÖüÜß,\-\;\.]{3,})$
```